# Mypy not resolving type correctly for compound conditions

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typing

Whenever `mypy` tries to resolve `Union`s, it seems to use the code flow to resolve the type:

```
import typing as typ


def foo(x: typ.Union[int, None] = None, y: typ.Union[int, None] = None) -> int:
    if x is None and y is None:
        raise ValueError
    if x is None:
        x = 1
    if y is None:
        y = 2
    return x + y


foo(1, 2)
```

Running `mypy` on the above results in Success.

---

However, if the conditions are slightly more complex (but still correct):

```
import typing as typ


def foo(x: typ.Union[int, None] = None, y: typ.Union[int, None] = None) -> int:
    if x is None and y is None:
        raise ValueError
    if x is None and y is not None:
        x = 1
    if y is None and x is not None:
        y = 2
    return x + y


foo(1, 2)
```

If I try to run `mypy` on it, I get the following errors:

```
main.py:15: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "None")
main.py:15: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
main.py:15: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("None")
main.py:15: note: Both left and right operands are unions
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

(line 15, is `return x + y`.)

---

I need to add to use the more complex option because when `x` is None, I want to compute it from `y` and viceversa (and I am using more variables than just two).

---

I could workaround this by adding a final condition:

```
if x is None or y is None:
    raise ...
```

but I am reluctant to add useless code to please the type checking.

---

Is there a better way of handling this situation?

(I am on Python 3.9, mypy 0.981)

Comment: There is no. Inference work in simple cases and only analyses one branch after another. `mypy` does **not** track complex conditions, involving multiple variables together (`x is not None or y is not None` means nothing for `mypy`). It works (roughly) by tracking type of each variable separately, narrowing if necessary (so `x: int|None; if x is None: ...` works). If a condition allows to deduce multiple facts **independently**, they are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can write assert expressions, but it's not very beutiful, I suppose

```py
def foo(x: typ.Union[int, None] = None, y: typ.Union[int, None] = None) -> int:
    if x is None and y is None:
        raise ValueError
    if x is None and y is not None:
        x = 1
    if y is None and x is not None:
        y = 2
    assert isinstance(x, int)
    assert isinstance(y, int)
    return x + y
```

Comment: This is also adding (almost) useless code to please the type checking :-/